# How hide the resources created by other vendors? (wordpress)

Tags: resources, wordpress, hide, vendors

I’m using Woocommerce Bookings on my website and I can’t find a solution to solve a problem. Into Resources tab that appears when you want to create a bookable product, you can manage resources created and select them from a dropdown list. **I would like to hide from the dropdown the resources that are created by other vendor users and display only my resources**. Is it possible?
Can you help me? I've already ask for problem to developers of Wc Vendors and Woocommerce bookings, but their response has not solved the problem...
Thank you!!!

Comment: Could you give link to your questions, or describe answers you got?

Comment: http://www.wcvendors.com/help/topic/how-hide-the-resources-created-by-other-vendors/#post-4918